# pass file as parameter using jquery in asp .net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In order to import data from file excel and display data in ascx page, I want to pass a file as a parameter to the controller via a jQuery function 
here is my code:
**view:**

```
<% Using (Html.BeginForm (new {enctype = "multipart / form-data"}))
                     {%>
                         <input type = "file" name = "file" />
                         <input type = "button" value = "OK" onclick = "Import (); return false;" />
                     <%}%>
```

**jquery:**

```
Import function () {
     var formData = new FormData ();
     formData = do something to get the file
     var Dialog = new MessageBox ();
     $ .ajax ({
         the type: 'POST'
         url: "/ Controller / Import"
         data: formData,
         cache: false,
         contentType: false,
         processData: false,
         success: function (View) {
             alert ("success");
             $ ("# DivList"). Empty ()
             $ ("# mainPageMainContent") append (View).;
         },
         complete: function () {
             ClosePatienter ();
             Dialog.MsgClose ();
         }
     });
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Import(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
      ......
      return PartialView("OtherView", model);
}
```

**When I execute this, file in my controller is null**
Someone can help me
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding the file to the formdata obj. Do something like this:

```
var formData = new FormData ();
//formData = do something to get the file
var uploadField = document.getElementById('uploadField');
formData.append("file", uploadField.files[0]);
```

Where "uploadField" is the id of your file input element.

Comment: thank you for your reply,
I tried but it did not even go through the controller

Comment: If the request does not even start you probably habe a JS error somewhere. Your posted JS code appears pretty incomplete but i thought that was a c/p issue.

Comment: what do you mean by incomplete?

Comment: There are missing commas after some parameters, and the spaces in the URL will probably create some issues too.